# Sitecore Menu Problem

Tags: sitecore

I have a strange error in my Sitecore environment that I've been ignoring since I started development (since it is only a minor inconvenience), and that is the fact that in dealing with large menus near the bottom, they get clipped by the bottom of the browser. Items then should detect the bottom and build upward, I guess, but they just don't. I have gone through the Sitecore Initial Configuration for Internet Explorer document several times.

Has anyone come across this?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: And which Sitecore version is it? Because it's a known issue in several versions.

Comment: +1 to your comment, Alex, because I noticed this was addressed in an update to 6.2. Unfortunately, I can't update my Sitecore installation, so the answer will remain unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the Sitecore site to your Local Intranet zone in IE, if it's not already.

(btw this is probably a better question for SuperUser, though doubt many sitecore folk monitor that stackexchange)

Comment: +1. Also, original link on SDN: http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Troubleshooting/All%20applications%20Inaccessible.aspx

Comment: Btw, I failed to find a single post tagged 'sitecore' or containing 'sitecore' on superuser.com. Are you sure people ask about Sitecore there?

Comment: Yan: no, just commenting that this isn't a development question. would be nice to get a sitecore tag started on SU but not sure you'd get enough volume.

Comment: I actually didn't post on Superuser for that exact reason, which is perhaps the wrong mindset. I'm sorry I haven't gotten back to you earlier, but it is in the Local Intranet zone.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer, seeing as it is probably helpful to users in the future, with the caveat that you may also have to update your revision of Sitecore (6.2).

Answer (score 0):

Please check on start up window of sitecore that Sitecore support this browser or not.